# PhpMyAdmin Export MySql to Json not showing UTF-8 encode (arabic)

Tags: php, mysql, json, phpmyadmin

Hello guys i have problem export MySql to Json format, it's not showing UTF-8 encode (arabic). But If export MySql to Sql format, it's showing UTF-8 encode (arabic). So how to fix it ?

Comment: do you select `utf-8` when exporting to JSON?

Comment: yes, but still not worl

Answer (score 0):

When exporting to JSON, I get character entities such as `\u16a0\u16c7\u16bb\u16eb` instead of the literal characters such as `ᚠᛇᚻ᛫`. This is expected, because PHP operates according to [RFC4627](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc4627.html), which requires displaying the UTF characters in this way (see section 2.5, for instance).

The .sql file format is free to use literal UTF characters, so it makes sense that you would see the expected output in a .sql file.

You haven't shown us the expected output or actual output, but I'm pretty confident this is the problem you're seeing and it seems to follow the RFC closely in this regard, so I would say it's the expected behavior rather than a problem.